# fbprophet was not installing in python (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, python-requests, pycharm, facebook-prophet

I'm not able to install the **fbprophet** in python from pycharm in windows i follows the facebook docs for install the module but keeps shown error while i installed pystan first but when i types

```
pip install prophet
```

then it pops this error
I stuck with this error how to resolve that please help me to resolve that
[error information][1]

````
 Running setup.py install for prophet ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Gaurav\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z01u
w28y\\prophet_364b14d05b244f05accc3a97dfa8ab92\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Gaurav\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z01uw28y\\prophet_364b14d05b244f05accc3a97dfa8ab92\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(token
ize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code,
 __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Gaurav\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-0z3rnn9g\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\gaurav\pycharmpro
jects\stockprediction\venv\include\site\python3.9\prophet'
         cwd: C:\Users\Gaurav\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z01uw28y\prophet_364b14d05b244f05accc3a97dfa8ab92\
    Complete output (285 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib
    creating build\lib\prophet
    creating build\lib\prophet\stan_model
    Importing plotly failed. Interactive plots will not work.
    INFO:pystan:COMPILING THE C++ CODE FOR MODEL anon_model_f5236004a3fd5b8429270d00efcc0cf9 NOW.
    WARNING:pystan:MSVC compiler is not supported
    stanfit4anon_model_f5236004a3fd5b8429270d00efcc0cf9_2516787927764637246.cpp
    C:\Users\Gaurav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECAT
ED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/prim/mat/meta/seq_view.hpp(145): warning C4267: 'return': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible
loss of data
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/prim/mat/fun/multiply_lower_tri_self_transpose.hpp(19): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from
 'Eigen::EigenBase<Derived>::Index' to 'int', possible loss of data
            with
            [
                Derived=Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>
            ]
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/prim/mat/fun/multiply_lower_tri_self_transpose.hpp(27): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from
 'Eigen::EigenBase<Derived>::Index' to 'int', possible loss of data
            with
            [
                Derived=Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>
            ]
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/prim/mat/fun/csr_u_to_z.hpp(28): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possibl
e loss of data
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/prim/mat/fun/matrix_exp_action_handler.hpp(118): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'doubl
e' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/prim/mat/fun/to_matrix.hpp(136): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', pos
sible loss of data
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/prim/mat/fun/to_row_vector.hpp(31): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int',
possible loss of data
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/prim/mat/fun/to_vector.hpp(31): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', poss
ible loss of data
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/prim/mat/fun/welford_covar_estimator.hpp(31): warning C4244: 'return': conversion from 'double' to 'in
t', possible loss of data
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/prim/mat/fun/welford_var_estimator.hpp(31): warning C4244: 'return': conversion from 'double' to 'int'
, possible loss of data
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\src\stan/io/dump.hpp(243): warning C4101: 'exc': unreferenced local variable
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\src\stan/io/dump.hpp(270): warning C4101: 'exc': unreferenced local variable
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\src\stan/io/dump.hpp(284): warning C4101: 'exc': unreferenced local variable
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/meta/operands_and_partials.hpp(42): warning C4267: 'return': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int'
, possible loss of data
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/meta/operands_and_partials.hpp(155): warning C4267: 'return': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int
', possible loss of data
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/scal/fun/bessel_first_kind.hpp(19): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'int',
possible loss of data
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/scal/fun/bessel_first_kind.hpp(20): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'int',
possible loss of data
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/scal/fun/bessel_second_kind.hpp(19): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'int',
 possible loss of data
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/scal/fun/bessel_second_kind.hpp(20): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'int',
 possible loss of data
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/scal/fun/modified_bessel_first_kind.hpp(19): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' t
o 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/scal/fun/modified_bessel_first_kind.hpp(20): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' t
o 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/scal/fun/modified_bessel_second_kind.hpp(19): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double'
to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/scal/fun/modified_bessel_second_kind.hpp(20): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double'
to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/scal/fun/rising_factorial.hpp(18): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'int', p
ossible loss of data
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/fun/cholesky_decompose.hpp(82): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'Eigen::EigenBa
se<Derived>::Index' to 'int', possible loss of data
            with
            [
                Derived=Eigen::Matrix<stan::math::var,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>
            ]
 
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(410): error C2660: 'stan::math::adj_jac_vari<F,Eigen::Matrix<stan::m
ath::var,-1,1,0,-1,1>>::count_memory': function does not take 2 arguments
            with
            [
                F=stan::math::internal::ordered_constrain_op
            ]
   
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(414): note: Reason: cannot convert from 'Eigen::VectorXd' to 'const
double'
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(414): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can p
erform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(333): note: see declaration of 'stan::math::adj_jac_vari<F,Eigen::Ma
trix<stan::math::var,-1,1,0,-1,1>>::build_return_varis_and_vars'
            with
            [
                F=stan::math::internal::ordered_constrain_op
            ]
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/fun/ordered_constrain.hpp(88): error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'void' to 'Eigen::Ma
trix<stan::math::var,-1,1,0,-1,1>'
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/fun/ordered_constrain.hpp(88): note: Expressions of type void cannot be converted to other typ
es
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(410): error C2660: 'stan::math::adj_jac_vari<F,Eigen::Matrix<stan::m
ath::var,-1,1,0,-1,1>>::count_memory': function does not take 2 arguments
            with
            [
                F=stan::math::internal::positive_ordered_constrain_op
            ]
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(246): note: see declaration of 'stan::math::adj_jac_vari<F,Eigen::Ma
trix<stan::math::var,-1,1,0,-1,1>>::count_memory'
            with
            [
                F=stan::math::internal::positive_ordered_constrain_op
            ]
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(408): note: while compiling class template member function 'auto sta
n::math::adj_jac_vari<F,Eigen::Matrix<stan::math::var,-1,1,0,-1,1>>::operator ()(const Eigen::Matrix<stan::math::var,-1,1,0,-1,1> &)'
            with
            [
                F=stan::math::internal::positive_ordered_constrain_op
            ]
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(617): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'stan::mat
h::adj_jac_vari<F,Eigen::Matrix<stan::math::var,-1,1,0,-1,1>>' being compiled
            with
            [
                F=stan::math::internal::positive_ordered_constrain_op
            ]
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/fun/positive_ordered_constrain.hpp(86): note: see reference to function template instantiation
 'auto stan::math::adj_jac_apply<stan::math::internal::positive_ordered_constrain_op,Eigen::Matrix<stan::math::var,-1,1,0,-1,1>>(const Eigen::Matrix<stan::math::var,-1,1,0,-1,1> &)' being compiled
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(412): error C2660: 'stan::math::adj_jac_vari<F,Eigen::Matrix<stan::m
ath::var,-1,1,0,-1,1>>::prepare_x_vis': function does not take 1 arguments
            with
            [
                F=stan::math::internal::positive_ordered_constrain_op
            ]
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(389): note: see declaration of 'stan::math::adj_jac_vari<F,Eigen::Ma
trix<stan::math::var,-1,1,0,-1,1>>::prepare_x_vis'
            with
            [
                F=stan::math::internal::positive_ordered_constrain_op
            ]
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(414): error C2664: 'stan::math::var stan::math::adj_jac_vari<F,Eigen
::Matrix<stan::math::var,-1,1,0,-1,1>>::build_return_varis_and_vars(const double &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'Eigen::VectorXd' to 'const double &'
            with
            [
                F=stan::math::internal::positive_ordered_constrain_op
            ]
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(414): note: Reason: cannot convert from 'Eigen::VectorXd' to 'const
double'
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(414): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can p
erform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(333): note: see declaration of 'stan::math::adj_jac_vari<F,Eigen::Ma
trix<stan::math::var,-1,1,0,-1,1>>::build_return_varis_and_vars'
            with
            [
                F=stan::math::internal::positive_ordered_constrain_op
            ]
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/fun/positive_ordered_constrain.hpp(86): error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'void' to '
Eigen::Matrix<stan::math::var,-1,1,0,-1,1>'
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/fun/positive_ordered_constrain.hpp(86): note: Expressions of type void cannot be converted to
other types
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(410): error C2660: 'stan::math::adj_jac_vari<F,Eigen::Matrix<stan::m
ath::var,-1,1,0,-1,1>>::count_memory': function does not take 2 arguments
            with
            [
                F=stan::math::internal::simplex_constrain_op
            ]
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(246): note: see declaration of 'stan::math::adj_jac_vari<F,Eigen::Ma
trix<stan::math::var,-1,1,0,-1,1>>::count_memory'
            with
            [
                F=stan::math::internal::simplex_constrain_op
            ]
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(408): note: while compiling class template member function 'auto sta
n::math::adj_jac_vari<F,Eigen::Matrix<stan::math::var,-1,1,0,-1,1>>::operator ()(const Eigen::Matrix<stan::math::var,-1,1,0,-1,1> &)'
            with
            [
                F=stan::math::internal::simplex_constrain_op
            ]
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(617): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'stan::mat
h::adj_jac_vari<F,Eigen::Matrix<stan::math::var,-1,1,0,-1,1>>' being compiled
            with
            [
                F=stan::math::internal::simplex_constrain_op
            ]
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/fun/simplex_constrain.hpp(97): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'auto st
an::math::adj_jac_apply<stan::math::internal::simplex_constrain_op,Eigen::Matrix<stan::math::var,-1,1,0,-1,1>>(const Eigen::Matrix<stan::math::var,-1,1,0,-1,1> &)' being compiled
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(412): error C2660: 'stan::math::adj_jac_vari<F,Eigen::Matrix<stan::m
ath::var,-1,1,0,-1,1>>::prepare_x_vis': function does not take 1 arguments
            with
            [
                F=stan::math::internal::simplex_constrain_op
            ]
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(389): note: see declaration of 'stan::math::adj_jac_vari<F,Eigen::Ma
trix<stan::math::var,-1,1,0,-1,1>>::prepare_x_vis'
            with
            [
                F=stan::math::internal::simplex_constrain_op
            ]
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(414): error C2664: 'stan::math::var stan::math::adj_jac_vari<F,Eigen
::Matrix<stan::math::var,-1,1,0,-1,1>>::build_return_varis_and_vars(const double &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'Eigen::VectorXd' to 'const double &'
            with
            [
                F=stan::math::internal::simplex_constrain_op
            ]
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(414): note: Reason: cannot convert from 'Eigen::VectorXd' to 'const
double'
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(414): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can p
erform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(333): note: see declaration of 'stan::math::adj_jac_vari<F,Eigen::Ma
trix<stan::math::var,-1,1,0,-1,1>>::build_return_varis_and_vars'
            with
            [
                F=stan::math::internal::simplex_constrain_op
            ]
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/fun/simplex_constrain.hpp(97): error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'void' to 'Eigen::Ma
trix<stan::math::var,-1,1,0,-1,1>'
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/fun/simplex_constrain.hpp(97): note: Expressions of type void cannot be converted to other typ
es
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(410): error C2660: 'stan::math::adj_jac_vari<F,Eigen::Matrix<stan::m
ath::var,-1,1,0,-1,1>>::count_memory': function does not take 2 arguments
            with
            [
                F=stan::math::internal::softmax_op
            ]
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(246): note: see declaration of 'stan::math::adj_jac_vari<F,Eigen::Ma
trix<stan::math::var,-1,1,0,-1,1>>::count_memory'
            with
            [
                F=stan::math::internal::softmax_op
            ]
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(408): note: while compiling class template member function 'auto sta
n::math::adj_jac_vari<F,Eigen::Matrix<stan::math::var,-1,1,0,-1,1>>::operator ()(const Eigen::Matrix<stan::math::var,-1,1,0,-1,1> &)'
            with
            [
                F=stan::math::internal::softmax_op
            ]
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(617): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'stan::mat
h::adj_jac_vari<F,Eigen::Matrix<stan::math::var,-1,1,0,-1,1>>' being compiled
            with
            [
                F=stan::math::internal::softmax_op
            ]
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/fun/softmax.hpp(78): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'auto stan::math::
adj_jac_apply<stan::math::internal::softmax_op,Eigen::Matrix<stan::math::var,-1,1,0,-1,1>>(const Eigen::Matrix<stan::math::var,-1,1,0,-1,1> &)' being compiled
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(412): error C2660: 'stan::math::adj_jac_vari<F,Eigen::Matrix<stan::m
ath::var,-1,1,0,-1,1>>::prepare_x_vis': function does not take 1 arguments
            with
            [
                F=stan::math::internal::softmax_op
            ]
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(389): note: see declaration of 'stan::math::adj_jac_vari<F,Eigen::Ma
trix<stan::math::var,-1,1,0,-1,1>>::prepare_x_vis'
            with
            [
                F=stan::math::internal::softmax_op
            ]
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(414): error C2664: 'stan::math::var stan::math::adj_jac_vari<F,Eigen
::Matrix<stan::math::var,-1,1,0,-1,1>>::build_return_varis_and_vars(const double &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'Eigen::VectorXd' to 'const double &'
            with
            [
                F=stan::math::internal::softmax_op
            ]
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(414): note: Reason: cannot convert from 'Eigen::VectorXd' to 'const
double'
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(414): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can p
erform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(333): note: see declaration of 'stan::math::adj_jac_vari<F,Eigen::Ma
trix<stan::math::var,-1,1,0,-1,1>>::build_return_varis_and_vars'
            with
            [
                F=stan::math::internal::softmax_op
            ]
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/fun/softmax.hpp(78): error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'void' to 'Eigen::Matrix<stan:
:math::var,-1,1,0,-1,1>'
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/fun/softmax.hpp(78): note: Expressions of type void cannot be converted to other types
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\src\stan/mcmc/sample.hpp(33): warning C4244: 'return': conversion from 'Eigen::EigenBase<Derived>::Index' to 'int', possible l
oss of data
            with
            [
                Derived=Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,1,0,-1,1>
            ]
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\src\stan/services/util/read_dense_inv_metric.hpp(38): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible l
oss of data
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\src\stan/mcmc/windowed_adaptation.hpp(49): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of da
ta
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\src\stan/mcmc/windowed_adaptation.hpp(50): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of da
ta
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\src\stan/variational/print_progress.hpp(52): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss o
f data
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\src\stan/variational/families/normal_fullrank.hpp(91): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'const int',
 possible loss of data
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\src\stan/variational/families/normal_fullrank.hpp(105): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'Eigen::EigenBase<Deriv
ed>::Index' to 'const int', possible loss of data
            with
            [
                Derived=Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,1,0,-1,1>
            ]
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\src\stan/variational/families/normal_fullrank.hpp(124): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'Eigen::EigenBase<Deriv
ed>::Index' to 'const int', possible loss of data
            with
            [
                Derived=Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,1,0,-1,1>
            ]
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\src\stan/variational/families/normal_meanfield.hpp(48): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'const int'
, possible loss of data
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\src\stan/variational/families/normal_meanfield.hpp(61): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'Eigen::EigenBase<Deriv
ed>::Index' to 'const int', possible loss of data
            with
            [
                Derived=Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,1,0,-1,1>
            ]
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\src\stan/variational/families/normal_meanfield.hpp(76): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'Eigen::EigenBase<Deriv
ed>::Index' to 'const int', possible loss of data
            with
            [
                Derived=Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,1,0,-1,1>
            ]
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\src\stan/io/cmd_line.hpp(32): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\src\stan/lang/rethrow_located.hpp(117): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of dat
a
    c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\src\stan/model/indexing/rvalue_index_size.hpp(20): warning C4267: 'return': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss o
f data
    C:\Users\Gaurav\AppData\Local\Temp\pystan_nmz8ripf\stanfit4anon_model_f5236004a3fd5b8429270d00efcc0cf9_2516787927764637246.cpp(5088): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of dat
a
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30037\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Gaurav\\AppDa
ta\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z01uw28y\\prophet_364b14d05b244f05accc3a97dfa8ab92\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Gaurav\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z01uw28y\\prophet_364b14d05b244f05accc3a97dfa8ab92
\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"
'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Gaurav\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-0z3rnn9g\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-he
aders 'c:\users\gaurav\pycharmprojects\stockprediction\venv\include\site\python3.9\prophet' Check the logs for full command output.


[facebook prophet installation docs][2]```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwfXh.png
  [2]: https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/installation.html
````

Comment: same error here, did you find a solution?